# How can I convert monthly data to bi-weekly data in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Using below query I'm getting monthly data (login details) and now trying to get Bi-weekly. I am trying to convert it.

Monthly I have like this and it is working in my query/code:

```
SELECT t.m_name as Title, COUNT(p.id) as Logins
FROM M_LOGINRECORD l, M_MUSER mu, M_PERSON p, M_TITLETYPE t
WHERE trunc(logintime, 'MM')= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6),'MM'
```

I am trying something like below for weekly, how can I achieve this?

```
SELECT t.m_name as Title, COUNT(p.id) as Logins
FROM M_LOGINRECORD l, M_MUSER mu, M_PERSON p, M_TITLETYPE t
WHERE trunc(logintime, 'DD')= to_char(sysdate +10,'dd/mm/yyyy')
group by t.m_name,trunc(logintime, 'DD');
```

Comment: `trunc(logintime, 'MM')= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6),'MM')` will only work monthly, if the number 6 is a parameter, which changes (also I don't see the group by, but I guess it's somewhere near). For weekly you would have `to_char(logintime, 'IW')= to_char(SYSDATE, -7),'IW')`, having in mind, that this number 7 should also be a parameter.

Comment: Overall I don't like the way this is implemented and I would like to improve the answer, but in order to do that, I need to see the complete query, since I see a Cartesian join between those tables `M_LOGINRECORD l, M_MUSER mu, M_PERSON p, M_TITLETYPE t`. What you need is a proper grouping in those queries; the way you wrote them now means you're hardcoding periods and it's a no go.

Comment: Many thanks!! I tried to give the whole query but unable to, hence just provided the part of it. If you want I can send it you to some email address. Let me try again :( Unable to too long characters :( error

Comment: don't try to include your query here in a comment - that will never work. EDIT your question. Note how the SQL in your question has been formatted now, do the same, there is a button in the toolbar `{}` to help you do that. just highlight the code and click that button

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying something like below for weekly, Can someone suggest on this, please ?

To get weekly groups you can use `TRUNC( datevalue, 'IW' )` which will truncate to the start of the ISO week (midnight Monday):

```
SELECT t.m_name as Title,
       COUNT(p.id) as Logins
FROM   M_LOGINRECORD l
       CROSS JOIN M_MUSER mu
       CROSS JOIN M_PERSON p
       CROSS JOIN M_TITLETYPE t  -- Did you really mean this rather than INNER JOIN?
WHERE  logintime >= TRUNC( SYSDATE + 10, 'IW' )
AND    logintime <  TRUNC( SYSDATE + 10, 'IW' ) + INTERVAL '1' WEEK
GROUP BY
       t.m_name,
       TRUNC( logintime, 'IW' ); -- This is redundant given the WHERE clause.
```

To get two-week groups then you can subtract the date from a reference point (for example: `TRUNC( DATE '1970-01-01', 'IW' )`, the start of the ISO week containing `1970-01-01`) which will give you the difference in days; then divide by 14 and floor the number to give the number of full two-week periods since that reference point; then multiply by 14 and add back to the reference point to get the start of the current two-week period:

```
SELECT t.m_name as Title,
       TRUNC( DATE '1970-01-01', 'IW' )
       + FLOOR( ( logindate - TRUNC( DATE '1970-01-01', 'IW' ) ) / 14 ) ) * 14
           AS two_week_period_start,
       COUNT(p.id) as Logins
FROM   M_LOGINRECORD l
       CROSS JOIN M_MUSER mu
       CROSS JOIN M_PERSON p
       CROSS JOIN M_TITLETYPE t  -- Did you really mean this rather than INNER JOIN?
GROUP BY
       t.m_name,
       TRUNC( DATE '1970-01-01', 'IW' )
       + FLOOR( ( logindate - TRUNC( DATE '1970-01-01', 'IW' ) ) / 14 ) ) * 14
```